# How print out specific text based on array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having difficulty trying to code this in vanilla javascript. Based on the random array element that is selected, I would like to output an `h1` with relevant info.

For example, if `#000000` is selected I would like an `h1` element to display the word "black".

Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var myArray = [
    '#4682B4', '#FFF5EE', '#000000'
  ];

  var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

  console.log(randomItem)
  document.body.style.background = randomItem;

  if (randomItem == myArray[2]) {
    // Display text "black"
  }
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Color names are arbitrary, so there's no built-in dictionary or logic that you just use off the fly. You'd need to either create another array that matches the hax array as reference or you could use an object literal or a Map.

Comment: What do you mean by _"display"_? Where in your document do you want the `H1` to appear? Does it exist already or do you need to create a new element?

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with text being from an array. It should be how to get English names of RGB colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the array of string to an array of objects containing two properties:

- `hex`: the hex color
- `color`: the name of the color

That way instead of having lots of `if-else` to set the color name you could only assign the values you want in the array and assign the `color` value (the color name) with a single assignment using `innerHTML` on the desired HTML element.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var myArray = [
    { hex: '#4682B4', color: 'Steel Blue' },
    { hex: '#FFF5EE', color: 'Seashell' },
    { hex: '#000000', color: 'Black' },
  ];

  var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

  console.log(randomItem);

  document.body.style.background = randomItem.hex;
  document.querySelector('#color').innerHTML = randomItem.color;
}

myFunction();
```

```css
body {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="color"></h1>
```